# How to load model from hooks file in ci3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to learn how to use hooks in ci3, is it possible to load a model from hooks file in CI3? because when I try to load the model it gives me this error:

```
 A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Undefined property: Http_request_logger::$load

Filename: hooks/http_request_logger.php

Line Number: 9
```

And

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function model() on null

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\vobot-cms\application\hooks\http_request_logger.php

Line Number: 9
```

and here's my hooks code:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Http_request_logger {

    public function activity_user() {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $this->load->model('./activity_user/MActivityUser');

       
        // log_message('info', 'GET --> ' . var_export($CI->input->get(null), true));
        $post = log_message('info', 'POST --> ' . var_export($CI->input->post(null), true));                
        // log_message('info', '$_SERVER -->' . var_export($_SERVER, true));

        $this->MActivityUser->insertLogActivity( $data = array(  
            'username' => (!$this->MActivityUser->getUsername() ? NULL : $this->MActivityUser->getUsername()),
            // 'domain' => $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"],
            'menu_name' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
            'activity' => $post,
            // 'ip' => $this->CI->input->ip_address(),
            'create_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'cms_id' => $this->MActivityUser->getUserId()
    ));
    return $data;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are loading the CI instance into the $CI variable but you are not using it to load your model.

```
$CI = & get_instance();
$this->load->model('./activity_user/MActivityUser');
```

should be

```
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->load->model('./activity_user/MActivityUser');
```